# Encrypt net share traffic

Tags: windows-7, networking, security, encryption, network-shares

I have two Windows 7 Professional workstations in my network. Workstation A is hosting a standard Windows network share which is accessed by workstation B. I would like to encrypt the (net share) traffic between Workstation A and Workstation B because there are other users in this network who should not be able to capture the traffic between my workstations.

Is there any (simple) solution for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to set up a secure tunnel between the two systems... Think of it like a two-computer VPN.

You can use this guide to setup a secure encrypted ssh connection fore windows file sharing:

http://www.bitvise.com/file-sharing

Good luck!